# Vim: Stop "existing swap file" warnings

Tags: vim

I have no idea why, but it seems that no matter how I quit out of Vim, it always leaves the swap files behind. So, whenever I open that file again, I get an irritating error about an existing swap file. Every time I have to choose "delete". I really wish this would stop. Is there anything I can put in my `.vimrc` to tell it, "just delete the swap file if it exists and leave me alone?"

Comment: How are you quitting VIM? It shouldn't leave the swap files behind, so rather than masking the problem, we're better off fixing it

Comment: Are you using a Unix OS and hitting Ctrl-Z?  If so, you're doing it wrong.  Please be specific on what you mean by "Quit out of Vim".

Comment: Perhaps you accidentally crashed vim on that file while being root and now vim can't delete it ? Maybe it's read only?

Comment: I use MacVim primarily, and quit it using the normal means (Cmd-Q). It never removes the sawp files, though.

Comment: @tdavis: Command-Q is not "universal".  It's normal for most Mac OS X apps.  However, it's not "universal" for all apps.

Answer (score 50):

In `.vimrc` add:

```
set shortmess+=A
```

From the docs `:help shortmess`:

> A   don't give the "ATTENTION" message when an existing swap file   is
>   found.

Answer (score 12):

There is plugin that can "Just do the right thing" automatically for Vim swapfiles: [vim-autoswap](http://svario.it/vim-autoswap).

From the homepage:

> Dealing with swap files is annoying. Most of the time you have to deal with a swap file because you either have the same file open in another window or it is a swap file left there by a previous crash.
>
> This plugin does for you what you would do in these cases:
>
> - Is file already open in another Vim session in some other window?
> - If so, swap to the window where we are editing that file.
> - Otherwise, if swapfile is older than file itself, just get rid of it.
> - Otherwise, open file read-only so we can have a look at it and may save it.

Answer (score 11):

Command-Q on the Mac OS quits the Terminal window, and crashes every application running in the window.

To quit VIM, you have to use ordinary VIM commands like `:q`.

Comment: As simple as possible, but not simpler.

Comment: Original poster mentioned that he is using MacVim, which is a gui app; the Terminal is not involved.

Answer (score 10):

See the VIM [recovery](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/recover.html) manual entry. You shouldn't be seeing these files normally, unless

1. your VIM instance is crashing
2. you're inadvertently running **two** VIM instances against the same file

I quite often do the latter, running 2 VIMs against the *same* file, in two terminals, without realising it. The 'swap file' message is the indicator that I'm doing this.

Perhaps you've got a VIM session running (backgrounded?) that you've forgotten about ?

Comment: Isn't a swap file different for a backup file? You leave a swap file around if vim crashed before closing the buffer properly.

Comment: So I've just launched 'vi Test.java', then background-ed it. Then I launch another 'vi Test.java'. And I get "Swap file .Test.java.swp already exists", which makes sense, I think

Comment: The swap file is created when opening a document in vim and deleted when the document is closed properly.

Comment: @Nik - my original answer referred to backup files. Is that what you're commenting about ?

Answer (score 5):

set noswapfile

Answer (score 4):

When a file is opened using the vim editor then corresponding swap file will be created with .swp extension. While editing the file if the system crashes then the created swap file will not be deleted. For this reason when you open the same file the message is displayed as ".filename.c.swp" already exist. In order to avoid this we have to delete all the swap files before we start our work.

```
rm filename.c.swp
```

name of the file . extension. swp

Comment: You forgot the . in front of filename

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you have not enough rights for some directory in the path to your current directory. It just happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your vimrc file.

```
if has("win32") || has("win64")
    set directory=$TMP
else
    set directory=/tmp
end
```